# How to delete an Azure Table after it is copied to another storage using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have 100 tables which i want to copy to another storage account frequently. After the copy is over, i want to delete the source tables.  I am able to copy entities inside tables to another storage account using ADF Copy Activity. But couldn't figure out a way to delete the source tables after successful copy.

I am using DataFactory .NET API to create pipelines, datasets etc. I thought of Custom Activity as the solution but not sure how to plug this actvity into pipeline through API ?

Any code samples or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As metioned that we could do that with Custom Activity.

> but not sure how to plug this actvity into pipeline through API?

We could use the [create or update Pipeline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/data-factory-pipeline) to create or update the pipeline API.

We could get more info about how to use custom activities in an Azure Data from  this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities).

The following is the snippet from the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities).

> 1.Create a custom activity .NET Class Library project implements that IDotNetActivity interface
>
> 2.Launch Windows Explorer, and navigate to bin\debug or bin\release folder
>
> 3.Zip the all of the file under bin\release folder and upload to the azure storage customactivitycontainer
>
> 4.Create Azure Storage linked service
>
> 5.Create Azure Batch linked service

We could use the [create or update Pipeline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/data-factory-pipeline) to create a pipeline that uses the custom activity

```
{
  "name": "ADFTutorialPipelineCustom",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Use custom activity",
    "activities": [
      {
        "Name": "MyDotNetActivity",
        "Type": "DotNetActivity",
        "Inputs": [
          {
            "Name": "InputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "Name": "OutputDataset"
          }
        ],
        "LinkedServiceName": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
        "typeProperties": {
          "AssemblyName": "MyDotNetActivity.dll",
          "EntryPoint": "MyDotNetActivityNS.MyDotNetActivity",
          "PackageLinkedService": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
          "PackageFile": "customactivitycontainer/MyDotNetActivity.zip",
          "extendedProperties": {
            "SliceStart": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyyMMddHH-mm}', Time.AddMinutes(SliceStart, 0))"
          }
        },
        "Policy": {
          "Concurrency": 2,
          "ExecutionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
          "Retry": 3,
          "Timeout": "00:30:00",
          "Delay": "00:00:00"
        }
      }
    ],
    "start": "2016-11-16T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2016-11-16T05:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false
  }
}
```

About how to operate azure storage table please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#delete-a-table).